# Latte crashing in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04, latte-dock

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 (Gnome 3.38.5) and Latte stopped working.

When I launch it, running applications are not shown and when I click Dock settings, it crashes.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Latte-dock is primarily intended for the Plasma desktop. That may be one reason why you have issues. The major reason, however, could be that you now may be running the Wayland display server rather than the traditional Xorg display server. You can confirm that from the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.

If you are running Wayland, then switching to an Xorg session probably will allow you to run Latte dock again.